# Are HP Certs Legit?

Tags: discussion

My medium sized company uses primarily Procurve products.  In an effort to learn some of the academic items that I may have breezed over during my self-taught efforts of the past and also to have something concrete to put on my resume for the future, I'd like to sit for all the HP exams in the next year or so.

The question is, are the HP ATA, ATP, ASE and MASE Networks well-regarded in the industry?  Thanks!

Comment: If you run in HP circles, I'm sure they have value. In Cisco shops, not so much. If you're looking for raise, that's between you and your employer.